# Problema de conexión de la base de datos Access (.accbd) en un ABM desarrollado en VB.NET con Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, ms-access-2010, oledb, visual-studio-2022

Tengo un ABM en visual studio 2022, en el cual estoy programando con Visual Basic .NET y necesito conectar una base de datos Access .accdb. Cuando voy a la pestaña de origen de datos en visual studio 2022 me salta el siguiente mensaje: Esta ventana no es compatible con el proyecto seleccionado. Para conocer los pasos para habilitar el enlace de datos, visite:
https://aka.ms/WinForms/DataBinding
Pero no logro poder resolver el problema.
[image: Error]

Intenté seguir los pasos de la página a la cual me mandaba visual studio 2022, pero no pude encontrar respuesta.
instale además el motor de base de datos AccessDatabaseEngine y probé también con AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.
luego probé abriendo un archivo que tenia un ABM desarrollado en visual studio 2010 y lo abrí en visual studio 2022 y sí me realizó exitosa la conexión con la base de datos, pero no en mi ABM.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TPwT.png)